# javascript code getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused with this, i know the code gives me the time difference from GMT, but for which city or country? How do i get the time difference between gmt and the time in Kabul Afghanistan.

```
            var now = new Date();
            alert(now.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Comment: It's the offset between current user's computer's timezone and GMT.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the value showing in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the offset of the [client local time zone](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp).

To get the offset of different time zone, use external libraries as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript), or just get the offset manually and use it, as explained [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329).